# How to Install Debian 10 to a RAID disk?

Tags: debian, raid, debian-installer

I have a problem when installing Debian into my system
My system is :

1. Ryzen 5 3500
2. MSI A320M-A PRO-MAX
3. 2 Pcs of Western Digital Green 120GB SSD

I successfully create a RAID0 array configuration from BIOS. I followed motherboard's manual and add 2 identical SSD to RAID array.

- I put Debian 10 installer (netinst) into my USB flashdrive
- I boot to UEFI model
- I add `dmraid=true` to the installer's menu when first boot
- I try graphical or non-graphical installer, but there's no RAID array displayed when it asked for installation disk

I follow this manual https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/SataRaid but stuck at step #4 as there is no RAID volume detected in disk partitioner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't trust the Hardware RAID. If that bios or motherboard ever failed, you're done. No recovery is possible. I would turn that off and go with a software type of RAID 10. That way you have a better chance of recovery from another source.

Comment: Fortunately, that's what I did last night. After stuck with this problem until mid-night I just install them with Software RAID. I just post it here so I can understand the problem better. Does Hw RAID that dangerous? Should it be faster than Software RAID?

Comment: Hardware RAID IS FASTER because it's bare metal (So to speak) But, it's encoded and written with that propriety BIOS code for that specific RAID card. Unless you have a card EXACTLY like that one with the same BIOS and chip set version to the letter, You will still loose your data.